# Дженерики, хорошо или плохо когда их много

Tags: c#, list, generics

У меня Интерфейс с дженериком `ILala<T>` и есть второй интерфейс, который будет содержать ссылка на предыдущий(его реализацию) `IBlala<T>`. И реализаций их равное количество допустим 10. В последнем интерфейсе, есть метод `bool CanUse()`, который говорит можем ли мы использовать данную реализацию или нет. Все реализации лежат в списке `List<object>`. Проблема, как пройтись `foreach` если для того что бы достать булевский метод нужно переводить тип к определенной реализации.

Внесу ясности. Я пытаюсь реализовать "калькулятор для разных типов" в интерфейсе `ICommand<T>` лежат основные операции (+ - / *). Далее в интерфейсе `ICalc<T>` лежит свойство типа `ICommand<T>` и метод `bool CanUse(string num1, string num2)`.
Далее у меня есть несколько реализаций, для `int, double, char, string`. Теперь пользователь вводит две строки. Неизвестно будут там числа или символ (либо дефолт строка). Я добавил все реализации в массив(список) и прогоняю введенные строки по методам `CanUse`, если ни 1 не сработал, значит отрабатывает реализация для строк(`string`).

Comment: Скорее всего вы делаете что-то не так

Comment: @АндрейNOP я в этом так же себя подозреваю, но как тогда реализовать это?

Comment: Полностью описать свою задачу (с точки зрения пользователя) и привести свою реализацию, опционально — поставить на вопрос метку [инспекция-кода]

Comment: Простой вариант - добавить самый базовый неGeneric интерфейс с методом CanUse. А про использование я спрашивал ещё в прошлом вопросе, как вы планируете это делать. Моё мнение - получилось неудобно, надо делать и пользоваться как то иначе.

Comment: @Monk ну вот да, я сейчас понял, что наступил на свои же грабли

Comment: Попробуйте в вопрос добавить информацию по конкретному кейсу, что вы пытаетесь решить. Из него выведите причину, по которой у вас появился один лист на все реализации. Тогда отвечающим будет проще понять, какие есть варианты решения.

Comment: @Monk, да добавил подробностей

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, это то что вы хотите сделать, но пытаетесь сюда втиснуть "дженерики".

```
public interface ICalc
{
    bool CanUse(object value);
}

public interface ICommand : ICalc
{
    object Plus(object firstValue, object secondValue);
    object Minus(object firstValue, object secondValue);
}

public class IntegerValue : ICommand
{
    Type[] types = new Type[] { typeof(int) };
    public bool CanUse(object value)
    {
        return types.Contains(value.GetType());
    }

    public object Minus(object firstValue, object secondValue)
    {
        return (int)firstValue - (int)secondValue;
    }

    public object Plus(object firstValue, object secondValue)
    {
        return (int)firstValue + (int)secondValue;
    }
}

public class StringValue : ICommand
{
    Type[] types = new Type[] { typeof(int) };
    public bool CanUse(object value)
    {
        return types.Contains(value.GetType());
    }

    public object Minus(object firstValue, object secondValue)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object Plus(object firstValue, object secondValue)
    {
        return firstValue.ToString() + secondValue.ToString();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var commands = new ICommand[] { new IntegerValue(),
                                 new StringValue() };

        var command = commands.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CanUse("строка"));

        var result = command.Plus("строка 1", "строка 2");

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Если реализация не была найдена, ищем реализацию строк(по вашему заданию)

```
        if (command == null)
        {
            command = new StringValue();
            // или 
            command = commands.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CanUse(string.Empty));
        }
```